# How to find a string from 1000's of files and replace is with another string from putty

Tags: linux, sed, grep, find, putty

In a directory I have sub-directories and in each sub-directories there 100s of file.What i want is to search and replace string from files with the occurrence of `c:/xampp to /opt/lampp/` 
I have tried :

```
    find . -type f -name "C:\xampp" -exec sed -i 's$C:\xampp$/opt/lampp$g' \;

    grep -rl "C:\xampp" /opt/lampp/htdocs/pepora/ | xargs sed -i 's$C:\xampp$/opt/lampp$g'
```

The same command worked for replacing an IP address:

```
    grep -rl 12.18.1.4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/peora/ | xargs sed -i 's/12.18.1.4/12.18.1.6/g'
```

This command worked and replaced the IP address but when i try the same with the "C:\xampp" to "/opt/lampp" its not working

does anyone have a solution for this.

Comment: You can't use `'$'` as alternate delimiters for `s` (it has a specific *regex* purpose) Why not `'s#C:\xampp#/opt/lampp#g'` or `'s|C:\xampp|/opt/lampp|g'`?

Comment: i have tried so many delimiter. but still not working

Comment: Oh, your are missing `'{}'`, try `find . -type f -name "C:\xampp" -exec sed -i 's|C:\xampp|/opt/lampp|g' '{}' \'` and also, why are you just using `-name "C:\xampp"`, that's 1 file, that looks wrong. Why not `find . -type f -name "xampp*"...`

Comment: Looking further, you don't need it at all if you are searching all files, what file name pattern are you looking for?? The `-name "stuff"` limits the files matched to those named `stuff`.

Comment: the file contain 
        uploadpath='C:\xampp\htdocs\peora\upload
i want it to make 
        uploadpath='/opt/lampp/htdocs/peora/upload
in every files that have that occurance

Comment: I get that, what are you using `-name "C:\xampp"` for? That limits your search with `find` to 1-file. If you want to search every file under the local directory, use `find . -type f -exec sed -i 's|C:\xampp|/opt/lampp|g' '{}' \;` removing  `-name "C:\xampp"` entirely.

Comment: Or optimally `find . -type f -execdir sed -i 's|C:\xampp|/opt/lampp|g' '{}' +`

Comment: i tried this command its executing but its not replacing anything or not made any changes to the file

Comment: is it `c:/xampp` you want to change or `C:\xampp`. You have it 2 different ways in your question and both are very different.

Comment: Here, it is taking `\x` wrong, use: `find . -type f -execdir sed -i 's|C[:][\]xampp|/opt/lampp|g' '{}' +` (if you just have 1-instance to change per-line, you don't need `'g'`)

Comment: yeah its kind of confusing .actually the files were in windows server so the paths are like C:\xampp\htdocs\....  But now we changed the files to Linux server environment so we need to change it to /opt/lampp/htdocs/.... what i want to change is C:\xampp

Comment: Try the command I just posted, it should work (also make sure you don't have weird DOS line ending and Byte-Order-Mark in the files coming from windoze) You can shorten it to `find . -type f -execdir sed -i 's|C:[\]xampp|/opt/lampp|g' '{}' +`

Comment: Thank you sir `find . -type f -execdir sed -i 's|C[:][\]xampp|/opt/lampp|g' '{}' +`    This command worked.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. There is very little `sed`, `find` and `awk` can't do. Good luck.

Comment: so if there is "\" or anyother special character in our code we want to replace we have to make it to [\] is that right sir?

Comment: You can always include a *character class* (meaning `[stuff]`) in the regular expression that would match any of the characters in `stuff` -- but more importantly here, it preserves the literal character (except for `'^'` as the first character) and prevents any other interpretation. So yes, if you have `'\'` you either need to escape it itself, or put it in a *character class* to insure it is taken as a literal `'\'`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help